# Can I use LabelFor() when the page inherits from IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Let's say, I've the following class definition:

```
public class Person
{
  [DisplayName("First Name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [DisplayName("Last Name")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And, I'd like to use **LabelFor(x =>x.FirstName)**, and so on. Unfortunately, the page inherits from

```
IEnumerable<T>
```

so there's no way to use lambda expression. Is there any workarround? Or, I do have to use the **Label(String)** version?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().LastName)
```

This will allow you to handle when the list is empty... very suitable for column headers. All you should check is for the cases when the list is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.**First()**.LastName)
```