# How to display name of MVC model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper

I have a class like this:

```
Public Class AuthKey
    <StringLength(45, ErrorMessage:="Name must not less then 5 characters and not exceed 45 characters.", MinimumLength:=5)>
    <Display(Name:="Name", Description:="Authentication name.")> _
    Public Property name As String
End Class
```

I'd like to view the property display name and description, not the property value. I try to both @html.display("Name") or @html.display("Description") and @html.displayfor(function (m) m.name) all show nothing. How to show it?

Comment: If your Model "Name" Property contain any value then Display/DisplayFor will display text

Comment: No, I would like to show the "Name" and or "Authentication name." value. Just like if i use html.labelfor, it will show the label name like this: <label>Name</label>. I just want the plain text of Name, without any html tag.

Comment: you want to add model class in view when you create view page then try

Comment: Use `DisplayNameFor()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, excellent, thanks! It shows what I need. DisplayNameFor show the name field. But I have another field which is "Description". How to show it?

Comment: @BennyChen, Its not used directly by any of the built in helpers, but you can create you own or access from `ViewData.ModelMetadata`. The [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578495/how-do-i-display-the-displayattribute-description-attribute-value) show a few options

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks for the links. It works! I ended up by access the metadata directly instead creating new custom helper. So here it is: @ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(Of AuthKey, String)(Function(model) model.name, ViewData).Description

Comment: you don't ask about description in  question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add model class in your view page after that try like this

```
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
```

[how-to-access-the-model-from-the-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113116/how-to-access-the-model-from-the-view)

Comment: This will display the name, but not the description. @stephenmuecke method works. I need to create custom helper or access the metadata directly.

Comment: @BennyChen, I only commented. This answer is correct based on you original question and you should mark it as accepted